# cast the Parent object to Child object in C#

Tags: c#, inheritance

Hi i want to cast the Parent object to Child object in C#

```
public class Parent
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
    public string MobileNumber {get; set;}
}
```

now the scenario is is a list of parent object and i want to generate list of child object so that i can have extended information

```
List<Parent> lstParent;
List<Child> lstChild = new List<Child>();

foreach(var obj in lstParent)
{
    lstChild.add((Child)obj);
}
```

as child class inherited parent class so the child class already have the parent class member i just want to fill them automatically so that i can populate datamember of child class

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If I understand your "I just want to fill them automatically" comment correctly, you want to create a new Child object that's populated with the values of the Parent, with default values for the new properties. Best way to do that is to create a constructor that copies the values:

```
public class Parent
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
    public string MobileNumber {get; set;}

    public Child (Parent parentToCopy)
    {
        this.FirstName = parentToCopy.FirstName;
        this.LastName = parentToCopy.LastName;
        this.City = parentToCopy.City;

        this.PhoneNumber = string.Empty; // Or any other default.
        this.MobileNumber = string.Empty;
    } 
}
```

Now you can use LINQ, like the answers above, to create a Child out of each Parent:

```
List<Child> lstChild = lstParent.Select(parent => new Child(parent)).ToList();
```

Note that this is very similar to @daryal's answer, but wraps the parent-to-child copying logic inside the constructor, rather than having it outside in the `new Child()` call.

Comment: The drawback of this approach is maintenance. If you add a field in the parent, you must also be aware to insert the assignment in the constructor of the child. In this scenario this seems pretty simple. In a more complex environment this can and will be forgotten. That is why I prefer the approach with reflection.

Answer (score 33):

I do so (*this is just an example*):

```
using System.Reflection;

public class DefaultObject
{
    ...
}

public class ExtendedObject : DefaultObject
{
    ....
    public DefaultObject Parent { get; set; }

    public ExtendedObject() {}
    public ExtendedObject(DefaultObject parent)
    {
        Parent = parent;

        foreach (PropertyInfo prop in parent.GetType().GetProperties())
            GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(parent, null), null);
    }
}
```

Using:

```
DefaultObject default = new DefaultObject { /* propery initialization */ };
ExtendedObject extended = new ExtendedObject(default); // now all properties of extended are initialized by values of default properties.
MessageBox.Show(extended.Parent.ToString()); // now you can get reference to parent object
```

Comment: Why not simply `prop.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(parent));`?

Comment: @Andrew I've been digging for a while now and still can't find an answer as to why the former would be preferable. I'd love to know why if there's a genuine reason, so I can better understand this mechanism; at the moment I can't see how `prop` (a `PropertyInfo` element of the array returned by `parent.GetType().GetProperties()`) could *ever* be different than `GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name)` (the `PropertyInfo` looked up using `prop`'s `Name`), which really just leaves me confused as to why the verbose version is used here.

Comment: Probably because Aleksey has been away for several years and never revised this answer. I guess he arrived to that working code after some effort and didn't realize it could be simplified. If my version works fine, I'd definitely go that way.

Answer (score 8):

This is what I came up with form my solution.

```
    public static void ShallowConvert<T, U>(this T parent, U child)
    {
        foreach (PropertyInfo property in parent.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            if (property.CanWrite)
            {
                property.SetValue(child, property.GetValue(parent, null), null);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why not the other overloads, `property.SetValue(child, prop.GetValue(parent));`?

Comment: Best answer on here IMHO, plus @Andrew's helpful comment.

Answer (score 6):

I did like this:

```
class Parent
{
  ...
}

class Child :Parent
{
  ...
  public Child(Parent p)
  {
            foreach (FieldInfo prop in  p.GetType().GetFields())
                GetType().GetField(prop.Name).SetValue(this, prop.GetValue( p));

            foreach (PropertyInfo prop in  p.GetType().GetProperties())
                GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name).SetValue(this, prop.GetValue( p, null), null);
  }
}
```

Comment: Why not simply `prop.SetValue(this, prop.GetValue(p));`?

Answer (score 3):

```
var lstChild = lstParent.Cast<Child>().ToList();
```

or

```
var lstChild = lstParent.ConvertAll(x=>(Child)x);
```

Both of these, however, assume that the `Parent` list actually contains `Child` instances. You can't change the actual type of an object.

Comment: Hmmm... This is just a type-cast. Descendant-specific fields will be not initialized properly. You may end up with NullReferenceException hive.

Comment: @YurySchkatula no, it will either fail with a type cast exception, or it will work fine; the OP asked for a cast; this **is a cast**. No initialization is required nor performed

Answer (score 2):

You may use reflection as well, but this is simpler for your case.

```
foreach(var obj in lstParent)
{
    Child child = new Child(){ FirstName = obj.FirstName, LastName=obj.LastName, City = obj.City};
    child.MobileNumber = "some mobile number";
    child.PhoneNumber = "some phone number";
    lstChild.Add((Child)obj);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to approach this solution is to have the `Parent` control the copy logic and `Child` will pass the copy source into the `base` constructor.

e.g. iterating on Avner's solution

```
public class Parent
{
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string City {get; set;}

    public Parent()
    {
    }

    public Parent(Parent copyFrom)
    {
        this.FirstName = copyFrom.FirstName;
        this.LastName = copyFrom.LastName;
        this.City = copyFrom.City;
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
    public string MobileNumber {get; set;}

    public Child (Parent parentToCopy) : base(parentToCopy)
    {
    } 
}
```