# How to initialize child class using function that returns a parent class?

Tags: c#, xml, inheritance

I've extended the `DataTable` class as follows:

```
class DataTableExtended:DataTable
    {
        public void specialMethod()
        {}
    }
```

I want to parse an XML node into this child class, which I tried to do with the following:

```
public DataTableExtended parseNodeToDataTable()
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            XmlNodeReader reader = new XmlNodeReader(this.resultNodes);
            ds.ReadXml(reader);
            DataTable dt = ds.Tables[1];
            DataTableExtended dte=(DataTableExtended) dt;
            return dt;
        }
```

It's throwing an `InvalidCastException`.  From what I've read so far, this is because it's not possible to cast a parent class to a child class.  Is that accurate?  If so, I know I can rewrite the `DataTableExtended` constructor so that it accepts a `DataTable` argument and copies that table's information, but I was hoping that there's a more direct way of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would write an extension method for DataTable  instead of subclassing it

```
public static class DataTableExtensions
{
    public static void SpecialMethod(this DataTable dt)
    {
        //do something
    }
}
```

--

```
DataTable dt = .........
dt.SpecialMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to read the `:` operator as `is a`. So a `DataTableExtended` is a `DataTable`. Note that this does *not* imply that a `DataTable` is a `DataTableExtended`, hence the failure to cast.

I think the best way of "casting" in this direction is to take an instance of the base class in your constructor, as you suggest.

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885823/1344760).