# Assign parent class data to child list

Tags: c#, linq, oop, inheritance

I have parent class

```
public class ImageInfo {}
```

and child

```
public class ImageInfoVM: ImageInfo {

//fields
public ImageInfoVM(ImageInfo img)
{
    this.name = img.name; //etc
}
```

I'm trying to read data from database with `IEnumerable<ImageInfo> model = db.ImageInfo.ToList()`
and assign this data to `ImageInfoVM iivm`, but no success at this.

I have tried this solution  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9885823/632224, which i think is what i need to do, but i'm getting error  `The class 'ImageInfoVM' has no parameterless constructor`.  in this query

```
List<ImageInfoVM> iivm = model.Select(m => new ImageInfoVM(m)).ToList();
```

Can someone help with this?

Comment: Why are you trying to assign `ImageInfoViewModel` to `ImageInfoVM`? What is the relationship between the two? And what constructors are available?

Comment: Typing error. Fixed now.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: what type is the `model` variable? :)

Comment: model is ienumerable<imageinfo>

Comment: Then it looks good to me. Isn't there a constructor in `ImageInfo` class by any chance?

Comment: No constructors in parent classs, only fields and validation properties which are not important for this problem i think..

Answer (score -1, accepted):

What do You do when You don't have "parameterless constructor"?

You create parameterless constructor.

I added empty constructor to my child class so now it looks like

```
     public class ImageInfoVM: ImageInfo {

    //fields
     public ImageInfoVM()
            { }
     public ImageInfoVM(ImageInfo img)
            {
                this.name = img.name; //etc

            }
}
```

and everything worked prefect..

Answer (score -1):

Could it be a typo?

**check your constructor name**  `ImageInfoVVM` instead of `ImageInfoVM`

```
public class ImageInfoVM: ImageInfo {

//fields
    public ImageInfoVVM(ImageInfo img)
    {
        this.name = img.name; //etc
    }
```

Comment: I made an typo error in question. In my code everything is ok.

Answer (score -1):

You didn't mentioned that you use Entity framework and LINQ to SQL.
Your problem is that LINQ to SQL didn't support constructors with parameters inside `Select` statement.

Your query is working with the `List` but not with `IEnumerable` type.
You need to create `List` of your models

```
    List<ImageInfo> model = db.ImageInfo.ToList();
```

Then your original code will work without parameterless contructors too

```
List<ImageInfoVM> iivm = model.Select(m => new ImageInfoVM(m)).ToList();
```